# What is the best way to set the ViewModel of a view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am new to the MVVM world and wondering what the best way is to set the ViewModel property of a new view when presenting that view?

I have tried to initialize the ViewModel class in the .fullScreenCover of the presenting view but that is causing me all sorts of problems.  This is what I have done:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @State var isActive = false
    var body: some View {
        Text("Tap here to go to SecondView")
            .onTapGesture {
                isActive = true
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isActive, content: {
                SecondView(viewModel: ViewModel(), isActive: $isActive)
            })
    }
    
}
struct SecondView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    @Binding var isActive: Bool
    
    init(viewModel: ViewModel, isActive: Binding<Bool>) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        self._isActive = isActive
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            $isActive = false
        }, label: {
            Text("Go back to FirstView")
        })
    }
}
```

The problem is the init method of the viewModel is being called many times.  I'm not sure if this is because the underlying FirstView is being redrawn despite not being on screen anymore or whether it has to do with the binding isActive var being accessed in the SecondView.  In any case so many viewModels are being created.  I'm not sure why this is.  But more importantly I want to know what is the correct way to initialize the viewModel of a new view.

What I am presently doing is creating the viewModel of the SecondView in the viewModel of the FirstView and passing the reference but that feels very wrong.

Comment: https://twitter.com/a_grebenyuk/status/1361329169620205570

Comment: Not sure what that link is about. I’m not asking about naming conventions.  I used that naming above to make things clear. Those are not the names in my code.  The question was about how to pass the view model. Not what to call it.  Thx.

Comment: You think you're talking about a "ViewModel", but there's actually a space in there: it's a "view model", the model for a view. It is confusing for the term "ViewModel" to persist now that we have modern tools like dots. Please help the industry evolve by changing the way you think about this.

Comment: the camel case indicates a space.  I believe that is convention.  I didn't call it a viewmodel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should use `@StateObject` when you initialize a `ViewModel`. If you only need it in the `SecondView`, then you don't need to pass it from the `FirstView` to the `SecondView` and you can initialize it in the `SecondView`:

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()
```

However, if you need a reference to it in the first view or you want it to persist regardless of SecondView being created, then you can initialize it in the parent view (`FirstView` in this case) using:

```
 @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
```

And then pass that object into the child view (`SecondView`):

```
SecondView(viewModel: viewModel...
```

And as you already have, it should be an `@ObservedObject` in the child view:

```
 @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
```

Alternatively, you could initialize it as an `@EnvironmentObject` and pass it into the environment instead of passing it directly from view-to-view through initializers.

---

I found a lot of people having trouble with this, so I made some YouTube tutorials if you want to get a better understanding:

[How to use @StateObject and @ObservableObject](https://youtu.be/-yjKAb0Pj60)

[How to use @EnvironmentObject](https://youtu.be/VWZ-h_N1wDk)

[SwiftUI Todo App with MVVM](https://youtu.be/wEf1YS4vyW8)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you so much.